# Importing DB retrieves only 50 tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i am trying to import a Database from phpmyadmin. But Each Time It is importing only 50 tables ( But the total No of tables are 110 And its size is 1.2GB) . 
I has also modified the maximum_upload_size =2000M , then also it is not getting importing properly.

Comment: Try it with mysqldump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be limitation with phpMyAdmin. Try the command line:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```